# MySQL DELETE statement is EXTREMELY SLOW in huge table

Tags: mysql, locking

I have table below :

```
CREATE TABLE crawl(
    url mediumtext,
    title mediumtext,
    maintext longtext,
    lastupdated tinytext,
    id mediumint AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)
);
```

and the table has 5 million rows huge
and query below is too slow

```
DELETE from crawl WHERE id = 10000
```

error message:

> ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

How can I optimize this?

Comment: Look like your table is locked by other process, use this to check it: `SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE Table LIKE 'crawl' AND Database LIKE '[DBNAME]' AND In_use > 0;`

Comment: No, There's no other process.
If I execute your query, the In_use is 1, so there's only one process using it.
I think the DELETE query do full scan (scan ALL rows)

but I don't know how to optimize this.

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: There has to be another process.  You can't lock-wait yourself, and a query by primary key would not cause a table scan.

Comment: It is _unlikely_ that the query is locking itself. You can use `SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_TRX` to see what transactions are running. To see who's locking who you can use `information_schema.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS` and `information_schema.INNODB_LOCKS`.